# How to abbreviate "deLuze"

Tags: surnames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you abbreviate surnames starting with Mc/O/D?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/how-would-you-abbreviate-surnames-starting-with-mc-o-d)

How would I abbreviate Jane deLuze?

If I were listing a numbe of people by initials, like John Doe or John Smith, I could use JD, JS etc.... but how would I do deLuze?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/how-would-you-abbreviate-surnames-starting-with-mc-o-d

Comment: Which country are you writing the list in? It will make a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, I would use **JdL**.  If absolutely constrained to two letters, then **JL**.

Answer (score 3):

The [MLA guideline for Spanish names](http://libguides.wwu.edu/content.php?pid=123723&sid=1066749) says:

> The Spanish *de* is not used before the last name when it stands
>   alone.
>
> example: Zayas, Maria de (María de Zayas)

The Chicago Manual of Style has an elaboration on this advice:

> When the particle *de* appears in a Spanish name, the family name,
>   under which the person is indexed, may be either the preceding or the
>   following name (depending in part on *how a person is known*).

In the common spelling of my middle name (dePano), the *de* does not stand alone, and I've observed these variations:

1. In the USA, my middle initial is considered to be *D*; on my driver's license, it's printed in all caps as DEPANO. My family has always spelled it DePano.
2. My relatives in my native country consider the initial to be *P*, and continue to spell it dePano. It's filed under *P*.

Here, the "how a person is known" clause of the CMoS guideline comes into play, as well as the locale.

- In the USA, abbreviating Jane deLuze as J. D. likely would not cause any
  confusion. Americans would tend to hear the name as starting with *D*.
- A Spanish-speaking locale might require J. L., or even J.D.L., to
  follow convention. (For example, I've seen Pedro de la Rosa
  abbreviated as Pedro D.L.R.)